# JQuery: passing concatenated variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code work:

```
$(".ab").css({'background':'#ce0000','color':'#EEE'});
```

But this doesn't:

```
f("ab");

function f(ab){

    var x = '".'+ ab +'"';

    $(x).css({'background':'#ce0000','color':'#EEE'});
}
```

Even tough `alert(x)` displays `".ab"` (dot ab between quotes)

Comment: Because you wrote _ab_ as it was a variable instead as text

Comment: The quotation marks of a string **literal** are not part of the value. `".ab"` creates the string containing .ab whereas `'".'+ ab +'"'` creates something like ".foo", i.e. the quotation marks are part of the string which is invalid (as selector).

Comment: My bad, I didn't mention that ab is passed as an argument to a function that contain this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes.

```
var x = '.' + ab;
```

That's it in case the name of your selector is stored in a variable named `ab`.

If you want to pass `.ab` verbatim, it's as easy as

```
var x = '.ab';
```